# How can I force Chrome to render the page while paused in debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I'm working with a web app that does some pretty heavy DOM manipulation via JavaScript, and I'm making extensive use of Chrome's Developer Tools to build out the page and the features. The problem is that sometimes, when the page pauses on either a breakpoint or a `debugger;` line, the page in the viewport doesn't get greyed out, doesn't get the "Paused in debugger" message, it doesn't highlight in blue the DOM element I have selected in the Dev Tools, and it doesn't redraw or update the render or anything when the DOM is manipulated by the Javascript. When I unpause the debugger and the code completes, the re-render happens as expected, but when I step through the code line-by-line in the debugger, the re-render doesn't happen until the code is complete and the debugger unpauses. This is really a problem when I'm specifically trying to debug some render-related issues. This is an inconsistent issue. For example, in the project I'm currently working on, there's an onResize() method that is run on initial page load, as well as (obviously) when the viewport is resized. If Chrome Dev Tools gets paused during the initial run of onResize(), it works as expected, rendering the changes to the page at every step along the way. But if it gets paused during a later run of that method, during an actual resize event, the problem I describe above happens and I don't see any changes to the rendering until the code has finished running.

Does anyone have any ideas why this happens, or what I can do about it?